# execlp() system call

Tags: bash, system-calls, dash

I want to call the ulimit shell command through a C program. right now, I have:

```c
execlp("ulimit", "ulimit", "-u", "%d", ulimit_a);
```

It compiles fine, but does not actually edit the user-id max process value when I later check it with `ulimit -a` (both the dash and bash version). The same was happening with `system()` as well, yet this seems to be a known issue for `system()`

Comment: And execlp() is not a system call, and you're lucky if that call works at all instead of crashing (as expected) -- the argument list of execlp should be terminated by a null pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The `ulimit` shell command only applies to the current shell and its descendants. It's a built-in not a separate command.

You cannot start a separate shell process, run `ulimit` in it, and expect it to have any effect on the parent process.

From C you should use the `getrlimit(2)` and `setrlimit(2)` functions to get and set the resource limits for the current process and its descendants. Though, judging by your approach, I guess they won't do what *you* expect them to do, either.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the maximum amount of processes a user can make permanently? IE not getrlimit/setrlimit because, like you said, those effect descendants of the process. I basically just want to make an interface for the root user to manage this.

Comment: @Connor Setting resource limits persistently (not "permanently", there is no such thing) is a completely different question that you may want to ask separately.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `pam_limits`, a PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) module for setting resource limits when a user session is created. You will have to configure PAM to use this module, and then you will have to configure the limits in `/etc/security/limits.d/`. See  https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_limits for more information.